# Nodejs server using more than 1 core intermittently

Tags: node.js, cpu, event-loop

I am running a nodejs backend server which is intermittently using more than 1 core CPU. I am not using any worker threads in my application code but I understand that nodejs uses threads for executing non-synchronous kernel APIs as mentioned in [the docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/cli.html#uv_threadpool_sizesize). My application connects to a database so it could be using DNS lookup which might be causing cpu usage to go beyond 1 core.

My question is, how do I ensure that DNS lookup is actually the reason for this? Is there a way I can see why usage is going beyond 1 core?

I am running my application inside docker container orchestrated through kubernetes.

Comment: It's up to the OS to schedule threads on multiple CPU cores, Node.js (probably) doesn't know about this. Can you provide some more background on why you're asking this question?

Comment: @robertklep I need to decide how much CPU should I allocate to my container. So need to understand whether allocating more than 1 core is really needed or not.

Nodejs will not know about thread scheduling but can I somewhere get info for how many nodejs threads are currently active and probably the task they are doing.

Comment: If the kernel only schedules one thread at a time, that might lead to a bit more context-switch overhead, but try it and see if the overall throughput suffers measurably.

Comment: (Single-core machine can run multi-threaded processes; that was normal 20 years ago, and OSes haven't forgotten how.  Multi-threaded processes don't *need* multiple threads to be running on different CPUs at the same time.)